# Get related object depending on its type EF core

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

what is the correct way to solve this issue:
Assum I have a table of objects:

```
public class Object
{
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public ControlType Type { get; set; }
public Guid ControlId { get; set; }
public IControl Control { get; set; }
}
```

and IControl is an interface which is implemented by 10 different control objects. Their types are described by ControlType enum. I want to store them in different tables, and while querying my Object I want my object to be included as IControl Control from Control specific table depending on its Id.

I know I can use TPH inheritance but my Control Table will be huge with a lot of null columns as  Controls have a lot of different properites depending on their type.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to dynamically query the `IControl` based on the `ControlType` and the `ControlId`.

Without adding the Validation (null checks, etc.), here is a way that I do it:

```
//assuming the names of your ControlType Enums exactly match the string name of their actual Type. 
//assume your Object is as follows
// var obj = new Object() {id = a8, Type = Ctrl8, ControlId = e3}
//context is the DbContext of EF.

//need to reflect on the EF Context and find the correct type 
var controlType = context.Model.FindEntityType(Enum.GetName(typeof(ControlType), obj.Type)))?.ClrType;

//search the context for the Control
var myCtrl = context.Find(controlType , obj.ControlId)
```

If you want a loose relation (no FK restraints), EF can allow you to find the object you just need some extra steps:

- Find the actual `Type` via Reflection.
- use the `DbContext.Find` with the respective `Type` and search for the `Id`.

Not too sure on what your `ControlType` actually is, so this code may need to adjust. I just use a `string` to store the Type of the loosely linked table. That way I dont have to adjust an `Enum` everytime I add or remove a POCO.